# One word for "unworthy of consideration"

Tags: single-word-requests

If you're faced with two options and one of them is 
more *worthy* of consideration, 
as in it takes less of your time, making the other option 
more "*unworthy* of consideration". 
It has a clear disadvantage that needs to be highlighted with a "strong" adjective.

"unconsiderworthy" was the word I thought would fit but it seems it's not a word. ([although atleast one other person has used it](http://google.com/search?q=unconsiderworthy))

edit: agreeing with the comments, changed the phrasing.

Comment: I've never heard nor can I find "considerworthy", therefore it's antonym makes no sense. There is "considerable". Did you look in a dictionary? I'd start with consider(able). Good luck.

Comment: @medica  I found several uses, including contemporary governmental. An example of early use:  "I am compelled to offer these remarks in answer to the inquiry of your correspondent G. W. D., which, 
if you considerworthy a place in your Magazine, their insertion will oblige, Sir,
Combustion." -Mechanics magazine. v. 2 (1824)

Comment: @ThirdNews - **This.** The above is an error wherein the space between *consider* and worthy* is missing. *consider* is the verb in the phrase "if you consider worthy of a place..." **(1824)**. Your searches can turn up any error. That doesn't make it a word. Just like *"thisisn't"* a word.

Comment: @medica, I always check for a difference between the OCR, and the text scan; your comment is inaccurate

Comment: @ThirdNews - no, it is your comment that is inaccurate and misleading. It should be pointed out. Please explain this phrase: "if you considerworthy a place in your Magazine"? What part of speech is it? How does it relate to *place*?

Comment: @ThirdNews Just because the OCR accurately transcribes text doesn't mean the source text isn't also missing a space.

Comment: @ThirdNews that sentence is riddled with errors anyway. Ranging from excessive punctuation to simply nonsensical ("their insertion will oblige, Sir, Combustion"). I would not consider anything from that sentence as evidence of use by a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply **[worthless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/worthless)**

> Having no real value or use

as in

> *One proposal was worthy of consideration, but the other was worthless.*

Alternatives might be

> - pointless
> - inconsequential
> - unproductive
> - unsuitable
> - inutile

Answer (score 2):

Consider ***[inconsiderable.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inconsiderable)***

> not worthy of consideration; insignificant

Answer (score 1):

[negligible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Negligible) may be an alternative:

> Not significant or important enough to be worth considering; trifling.

Comment: negligible doesn't imply the unworthiness enough. Option 2 is not just not important, but it has a disadvantage that needs to be highlighted with a "strong" adjective.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you rephrase your question to make clear what you are looking for so other users may help too.

Comment: Do  'unacceptable' or inadmissible' convey the meaning you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**[Indign](http://www.yourdictionary.com/indign)** undeserving; unworthy disgraceful

Comment: This word is archaic and obsolete (or poetic). At least you should list that along with your definition.